# API Messenger Get conversations from plateform instagram

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

Using the API graph messenger for retrieving conversations on business account Instagram which has less than 1000 followers.
Using Page token, it returns an empty data with platform=instagram like below:
https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/168686456992372/conversations?platform=instagram

Messenger has already announced that the API is expanding for all businesses on Instagram.

Please If someone has an idea how to solve this issue, it's very helpful

Thank you so much

best Regard

Comment: Same issue for me. Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Same issue, @OrkhanAlikhanov were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @Naeem I posted my experience as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use this endpoint.

```
[your_page_id]/conversations?fields=messages{from,to,message,created_time,id}&platform=instagram
```

You will get conversations from ig.

```
required:
- instagram_basic
- instagram_manage_comments
- instagram_manage_messages
- pages_manage_metadata
- pages_messaging
- read_page_mailboxes
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, it turned out to be impossible without getting [Advanced Acccess](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/access-levels/#advanced-access) verification for your app for the scope `instagram_manage_messages` as indicated at [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram/overview#testing-your-app-before-app-review):

> While the app is in development mode/**standard access**, all Instagram Messaging APIs (Send API, Webhook, *Conversation API*, etc.) will only work for users that have a role in the app.
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> Conversation API will **only** be showing threads/messages for users that have a role in the app.

I might wrong in my conclusion though.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation of Facebook, currently we cannot fetch messages of our Instagram business account.

> Limitations:
> Instagram Messaging is available for all Instagram Professional accounts for businesses. However, **currently**, Instagram Messaging is *only available for Instagram Professional accounts for **Creators*** with less than 500k followers.

Comment: Source Documentation Link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/overview#limitations

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a test account, and you have not get the advanced access yet. Advanced access allows you see all instagram messages (from any user), otherwise, if you only have standar access you only will get messages from a user who has a role in your app.
Try relate the instagram account with the facebook account of any user who has a role in your app, when both accounts will be related, try send a message and get it through the api graph.

Advanced access for instagram should be requested in *your app panel/app review/permissions and roles* for the next permissions:

- instagram_basic
- instagram_manage_comments
- instagram_manage_messages

Answer (score 0):

To get instagram conversation data you need to follow below steps:

1. Go to the roles inside app roles
2. click on edit roles in business manager
3. click on Assign People then click on user name and gave him/her full control then you will able to get instagram data
4. after this complete your implementation with this user
5. then raise app review then provide your implementation then you will get advance acces through this you can get end users chat data